# Raspberry Pi setup

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I feel that I have a bit of an unusual situation and haven't been able to find much to resolve it.

I recently got out my pi after almost 2 and a half years. I hadn't done much development then either, so I would say I know less than a Beginner. So I apologise if this is a stupid question.

I connected the SD card to the pi, the power, ethernet to my laptop, and HDMI to my projector. Once I started it, I could see the pi was doing a bunch of boot activities and finally stopped at:

> My IP address is 192.168.2.2
>
> Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 raspberrypi tty1
>
> raspberrypi login: _

I do not have a keyboard to connect to so, I googled around and ssh'd into the pi.
So now, the terminal on my laptop is ssh'd into the pi and my projector is still showing the same screen with the command prompt text I have written above.

I remember being able to see the GUI of the raspberry pi. To tried to connect to vnc, I followed the steps listed in an article and did the following:

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lxsession
>
> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ tightvncserver
>
> New 'X' desktop is raspberrypi:1
>
> Starting applications specified in /home/pi/.vnc/xstartup
>
> Log file is /home/pi/.vnc/raspberrypi:1.log
>
> pi@raspberrypi ~ $

I am not sure what to do from here on.

I want to able to see the interface of the pi on the projector connected to the pi or, if I can only run applications and see on the projector then, set up the VNC on my terminal and be able to login on the screen showing on my projector:

> My IP address is 192.168.2.2
>
> Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 raspberrypi tty1
>
> raspberrypi login: _

Please tell me what I can do, I have tried looking on Google/SO but haven't been successful.
I want to be able to see the pi interface on my projector and control it with my mac for now (this is probably done via ssh, I'm guessing?), and may be later, I will buy an external laptop for the pi.

Any help will be great! You can even just direct me in the right way!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Excited to start using the pi now that I have the time and abilities!

Comment: I think you just type `startx` to start the gui/window manager

Comment: That is, if you are on it with a keyboard, if you want to do this remotely you'll need a vnc server on the pi and a vnc client on your mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your pi, open a terminal and type `raspi-config`, under one of the options you'll be able to set the pi to boot into GUI mode, otherwise this is done by typing `startx`. I'm assuming this is your problem.

It sounds like you're following a tutorial about how to setup vnc, I remember the one from the official raspberry pi site being good, if you still need help with that:
 https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thank you so much for your help.
I gave the `startx` command. Also, in `raspi-config`, I changed the boot to desktop and then tried to update the pi.
Unforunately, now, every time I try to ssh to the pi from my terminal, the _Operation times out_.
Also, I tried connecting a mouse to the USB port but it doesn't seem to work - is there some way I can check if my ports have been damaged?

Thanks again!

Comment: So, you have a gui now right? I'm not sure what would be causing either of those problems, as what I suggested is exactly how I set up my pi's. It could be a problem with your mouse, or it could be the port, another stack exchange site may be able to help with that. There's no reason ssh should have stopped working, you haven't changed anything that would influence that. Sorry I can't be of more help at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris, I am still not able to ssh into my pi - not sure why. I'll keep trying